# Math Calculation with Woocommerce Product Price Field

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, advanced-custom-fields

I am working with Woocommerce and Advanced Custom Fields.

I would like to divide the Woocommerce product price by a custom field and then output this as another custom field so it can be shown on the product page.

Example would be a pack of 10 pens, where I also want to show the cost-per-pen as a custom field, allowing customers to compare the price-per-unit across multiple skus.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you could do something simple like:

```html
<?php
$price = $product->get_price_html();
$customfield = get_field('myfield');

// simple maths
$price_piece = $price / $customfield;
?>
  <div>
    <?php echo $price_piece ;?>
  </div>
```

There is also a helpful page for woocommerce product information
https://www.businessbloomer.com/woocommerce-easily-get-product-info-title-sku-desc-product-object/. I didnt checked the code, but you get the idea, hope that helps!